# SVG filter not visible when using custom viewBox

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

Why is setting an svg viewBox to say `0 0 1 1` causing my filter to disappear? I also tried playing around with `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width` attributes as well as changing `primitiveUnits` attribute, nothing did work. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

svg circle {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">
      <defs>
        <filter id="halo1">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" filter="url(#halo1)"></circle>
    </svg>
    
   <svg>
      <defs>
        <filter id="halo2">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" filter="url(#halo2)"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>

</html>
```

Fiddle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/6x34urzg/14/

Comment: The stdDeviation="3" is way too big for the size of the box. The viewBox="0 0 1 1" implies the width and the height is 1. For this viewBox try using stdDeviation=".03" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image is scaled from 1x1 (the `viewBox="0 0 1 1"`) to 100x100 px the standard deviation (`stdDeviation="3"`) is also scaled. The circle with the filter is still there but 100 time too big.

If you set the standard deviation to 1/100 (`stdDeviation=".03"`) you will get the same result as the other SVG.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

svg circle {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">
      <defs>
        <filter id="halo1">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation=".03" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" filter="url(#halo1)"></circle>
    </svg>
    
   <svg>
      <defs>
        <filter id="halo2">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" filter="url(#halo2)"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the CSS you know insert CSS to HTML like Internal CSS and Inline CSS. Internal CSS is you write css on in inside  on  tag and that tend general for use to give style on SVG. While, Inline CSS used to write css on unique element on tags like your program(coding). Although you have writenn css svg, your svg on "Hallo1" disappear because your program have write inline CSS viewBox="0 0 1 1"make your svg "Halo 1" disappear. Moreover, viewBox="0 0 1 1" make your circle dissapear because weight=1 and height=1 so that cirle which resulted so small and you cannot see that. To solve that problem you can change your viewBox become 'viewBox="0 0 100 100" '